# Components not detected in Joomla 1.5.23

Tags: joomla1.5

I'm in the middle of moving a site to a new server. All files and database contents have already been transferred. The pages I've Googled about moving a Joomla site to a new server have all said that all I'd need to do after the move is make sure that configuration.php was using the new database's connection details. I've done all of this but for some reason, Joomla can't seem to detect my components. I can't even log in to the administrator site because logging in just throws an error (specifically: "mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method stdClass::onAuthenticate()").

Are there any other settings or configuration files I can check to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Seems like some of your files are missing! Re-check if you've transferred all you files. Also, make sure that in configuration.php, you set the `$live_site` variable correct.

Comment: that appears to be the case. I transferred the files from server to server using scp but it seems to have missed some files. I don't know why.